# Fluent Migrator throws Invalid character in path error when running

Tags: msbuild, fluent-migrator

I run into this problem - when I run MSBuild task to execute migrations, it throws an error:

> While executing migrations the following error was encountered:
>   Illegal characters in path.

removed the last migration I added yesterday - same problem.
The version I'm using is 1.1.0 from NuGet.

Answer (score 5):

I was running into this error when I was trying to execute some inline sql in my migration.

My problem was that I was using `Execute.Script` (which expects a file name) instead of `Execute.Sql`